# Set the Path of database in android device sdcard?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm handling the database through the sqlite manager and put into the asset and gave the path where I want to create my database.

It's works fine in Emulator but when use the real device it's not working (DATABASE NOT CREATED ) ....

I tried a lot way to sort out but couldn't get the solution ..

This is what I did :  private static String DB_PATH= Environment.getDataDirectory() +

"/data/my_package_name/databases/";

Comment: have you looked at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: when I run the app first time , database doesn't exist and in emulator database created on the path but when I use the real one ... nothing will happen @Red Cricket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can resolve this problem using this :

private static String DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/data/my_package_name/databases/";

:) silly one, But now I'm aware from all the methods

Comment: Environment have 6 methods to handling the data where you want to store

Answer (score 0):

inside yout Database Class which extends the `SQLiteOpenHelper` you should have below String DB_PATH and DB_NAME.

```
public String DB_PATH = "data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/databases/"; // path of your datbase
public static String DB_NAME = "xyz.sqlite";// your database name
```

Comment: yes , both I have .... when I run the app first time , database doesn't exist and in emulator database created on the path but when I use the real device ... nothing will happen @Bhavesh

Comment: @user2078315: can you please post your whole code of java file which extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: As a said earlier that i am using SQLITE MANAGER for creating the database and put into the asset folder .

Comment: Am not extending  SQLiteOpenHelper @Bhavesh